# Android Google Maps Touch Events

Tags: android, google-maps

I Want an idea on google maps in android .Thins is whenever i touch geopint location it should pop me up a dialog box. Any one please answer my question with one example.

Thank you.....

Answer (score 0):

There's an brilliant library for maps called **"Polaris Maps"**. 
It's pretty easy to use
I think it is going to solve your problem.

There it is
http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=824

Comment: Thank you, i have resolved my problem with OverlayItems in google maps